# Code optimization techniques in extjs?

Tags: optimization, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am dynamically creating some controls in a page. it will become slow when we have some fifty controls.

what are the code optimization techniques/ guideline used in extjs?
Is there any specific methods which will slow down the entire loading?

Comment: Sencha has just published an article on performance techniques (http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-4-1-performance/). This may not be directly relevant to your situation, but useful to consider nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tips are

- Use Ext.container.Container rather than Ext.panel.Panel.
- Instead of adding ext components, use XTemplate with data view to load similar controls.
- if you are using many images then use image sprites - An image sprite is a collection of images put into a single image. A web page with many images can take a long time to load and generates multiple server requests.
  Using image sprites will reduce the number of server requests and save bandwidth.
  http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 6):

Sencha has great posts:

[Ext JS 4.1 Performance](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-4-1-performance/) about:

- Network latency which affects initial startup time heavily, but also data store load time.
- CSS processing.
- JavaScript execution.
- DOM manipulation.

[Optimizing Ext JS 4.1-based Applications](http://www.sencha.com/blog/optimizing-ext-js-4-1-based-applications/) about optimization tips and the Page Analyzer tool.